# debugging assembly x-86 using dosbox

Tags: assembly, linked-list, dosbox

since i still don't know a method to write&compile assembly x-86 linked lists programs via ide(emu8086 doesn't support linked list struct as far as i know)
i wrote it in notepad and compile using dosbox
the code compiles without errors and when i run via
g4e(the adress of mov ah,4ch
i get to input a number and there the program gets stuck

here is my code

```
node struc

 value db ?
 next dw ?

node ends


dseg segment

list node <'1',3h>
    ORG 3h
    node <'3',6h>
    ORG 6h
    node <'7',9h>
    ORG 9h
    node <'9',-1> 
searchInt db 0
counter1 db 0
welcome db 'Please enter a number between 1-10$'

dseg ends          

sseg segment stack
db 10h dup (?)    
sseg ends

cseg segment
assume cs:cseg,ds:dseg,ss:sseg

start:
   mov ax,dseg
   mov ds,ax
   lea si,list
   mov dx,offset welcome
   call print
   userInput:
   xor ax,ax
   mov ah, 1
   int 21h

   cmp al,30h
   jb userInput
   cmp al,39h
   ja userInput
   jmp searching

   searching: 
   lea si,list
   cmp [si].value,al
   je counter
   cmp [si].value,-1
   je sof
   mov si,[si].next
   jmp searching

   counter:
   inc counter1
   cmp [si].value,-1
   je sof
   jmp searching


   print proc ;procedure for printing messages 
   mov ah,9h
   int 21h
   MOV dl, 10
   MOV ah, 02h
   INT 21h
   MOV dl, 13
   MOV ah, 02h
   int 21h ;start a new line
   ret
   print endp

   sof:
   mov ah,4ch
   int 21h

 cseg ends
 end start
```

can someone point out where is my problem ?

Comment: The problem is `lea si,list`. at the beginning of `searching`. This sets `si` always to the start of the list. and overrides the `mov si,[si].next`.

Comment: thanks i already removed that line since in the start i already wrote that line.
now something weird is happening,once in a while it suddenly accepts the user input ,which makes this code very weird

Comment: You should not remove it but move it just before the first `jmp searching`.The next problem are the two `cmp [si].value,-1` which should be `cmp [si].next,-1`.